# Displaying a sibling <div> on <a> hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The HTML structure of the header is not ideal, but cannot be changed at this time.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a class="speakingdropbtn" href="">Speaking</a>
        <div class="speakingdropdown">
            <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Assemblies</a>
            <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Religious</a>
            <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Corporate</a>
        </div>
        <a href="">Products</a>
        <a href="">Media</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
    </nav>
```

I'm trying to make it display the div with the class "speakingdropdown" when I hover over the anchor tag with the class "speakingdropbtn"

What CSS or JS or JQuery would I need to use to make that happen? I can post CSS, but there's a ton of it because the whole header is fully responsive.

Comment: Because of the stupid way I made the header in the first place, so now there's 200+ lines of CSS based on those being anchor tags and I don't know if changing them would help :/

Comment: From a semantic point of view, those links should be wrapped in `li`s in a `ul` and `.speakingdropdown` should be a sub-`ul`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `css` adjacent sibling selector `+`, `:hover` pseudo class

```css
div.speakingdropdown {
  display: none;
}

a.speakingdropbtn:hover + div.speakingdropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a class="speakingdropbtn" href="">Speaking</a>
  <div class="speakingdropdown">
    <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Assemblies</a>
    <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Religious</a>
    <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Corporate</a>
  </div>
  <a href="">Products</a>
  <a href="">Media</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
  <a href="">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're a blessed man. That finally worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.speakingdropbtn').hover(function() {
  $('.speakingdropdown').show();
},
function() {
  $('.speakingdropdown').hide();
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using CSS only simply is *not enough jQuery*.

Answer (score -1):

Without any css styles, this is the most basic implementation. We hide the dropdown and then on hover we use jQueries .show() method.

```js
$(".speakingdropbtn").hover(function(){
  $(".speakingdropdown").show()
})
```

```css
.speakingdropdown {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a class="speakingdropbtn" href="">Speaking</a>
        <div class="speakingdropdown">
            <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Assemblies</a>
            <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Religious</a>
            <a href="" style="text-indent:25px;">Corporate</a>
        </div>
        <a href="">Products</a>
        <a href="">Media</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: @guest271314 has a more simple css only option.